# Why do my images not line up properly?

Tags: css, layout, css-float

CSS is very new to me though I am willing to learn, but I cannot solve this one.

I have an unordered list containing seven small images down the left hand side of a page within a container.

I want to line up three images across the bottom of the page underneath the list.

These bottom three images seem to line up where the right of the column would be if it stretched down and then go out of the container.The images are in a table but if there is a better way, I'll be happy to use it.

There's a lot of coding so I'm not sure what to put down here, but the URL is:

http://www.c5d.co.uk/coursehistoryfour.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can manage your width by managing the width of `td`, then image width 100%

```
<table>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td witdh="33%"><img width="100%" height="" alt="JWK" src="http://www.c5d.co.uk/JWK.jpg" title="J W Kenworthy" class="renouf"> J W Kenworthy: The First President</td>
<td width="33%"><img width="100%" height="" alt="" src="http://www.c5d.co.uk/parnaby.jpg" title="Henry Parnaby" class="renouf">Rev<sup>d</sup> Henry Parnaby: The First Captain</td>
<td width="33%"><img width="100%" height="" alt="" src="http://www.c5d.co.uk/renouf.jpg" title="Tommy Renouf" class="renouf">Thomas Renouf: Course Designer</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

But it is better to use `div` instead of `table` and
you are putting large image size that you have to resize in a actual size that you see on the browser to increase your browser load speed.

Comment: Thanks. It's works well. Maybe I need to re size the images so they are all the same size

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest you to use `div`s instead of `table`s. I made a short fiddle where you can check how I would do that [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/amzUB/2/)

Comment: Thanks. I'm not sure what you mean with a fiddle. I'm new to this

Comment: jsFiddle text inside my answer is a link where you can see my code.

Comment: Thanks very much for clarifying. I said I was new to this